# How to use map function on object containing different key in select tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

need to show Movies in the select tag in which options are 2018,2019,2020 etc and when a year gets selected need to show corresponding Movies

```js
const data = {
  2018: ["Avengers 1", "Now you see me", "Fast and Furious 7"],
  2019: ["Avengers 2", "Now you see me 2", "Fast and Furious 8"],
  2020: [
    "Final Avengers Movie(Iron man dies)",
    "Now you finally used Lenskart",
    "Covid Came",
  ],
  2021: ["Covid Returns"],
  2022: ["Adventures of Saiman", "Adventures of Shaktiman"],
};

const App = () => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState([]);
  
  return (
    <div id="main">
      <select name="select">
        {Object.keys(data).map((year) => (
          <option value={year}>{year}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be trying to use the value of the `select` at all, maybe start with e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.